# Vertical Bar: Symbolism

Tags: c++

First of all, What should print to the screen if I do this:

> cout << '\x7E';

What I'd like to know is what is the `\x??` for the "|" symbol?

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/index.htm and search for "vertical bar"

Comment: Can't you just use `'|'`?

Comment: @MooingDuck After they make their redesign less broken.

Comment: You shouldn't multipost like this! the last part is really a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have tried it.

As for the symbol, it's octal **174** or hex **7C**:

```
cout << '\174';
cout << '\x7C';
```

You can find this stuff yourself if you search for "ascii table":

[image: ASCII table]

You can even work it out yourself:

```
int c = (int)'|';
cout << dec << c << endl;
cout << oct << c << endl;
cout << hex << c << endl;
```

Comment: Of course that assumes the OP isn't running on an old IBM Mainfraim that uses EBCDIC. Or some embedded system with a completely non-standard character set. [Unlikely, but still not ENTIRELY impossible].

Comment: Thank you, I am running Windows Server in parallel on a Mac.

Comment: @MatsPetersson In which case, they can run the code snippet I suggested to determine the correct value on their system.

Comment: One easy way to promote characters is `cout << hex << +'|' << '\n';`

Comment: Cool, thanks @MooingDuck - I didn't know that syntax/trick.

Comment: To my knowledge it's just about the only use for the unary `+` operator :/

Answer (score 1):

Printing `\0x7E` will print the tilde character '**~**'

The ASCII value of the pipe character is **0x7C** which is **124**.

You can find out the value of all characters by looking them up in a table: [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

You could always use the character itself:

```
cout << '|';
```

Will work as expected.

---

In a case statement, you can either use the value of the char directly, or a character:

```
switch(character){
  /*
   * The following three cases are identical. 
   * Not even sure if the compiler will allow it.
   */
  case 124:
  case '\0x7C':
  case '|':
    do_stuff(character);
    break;
}
```

Comment: But would '\x(whatever)' work?

Comment: `\xXX` where XX is an hexadecimal value. Sure.

Comment: `\oXXX` will work with octal values and `\XXX` will work with decimal values.

Answer (score 0):

The `\x` indicates that the `char` is being given as hex value of the system's character set.

Comment: No, `\x` does **not** mean ASCII. It could use an entirely different charset, depending on your platform.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Fixed. I appreciate the criticism. I often use ASCII as a shorthand for "character set" since it is largely the most common charset in use.

Comment: One could argue that UTF-8 is more common in actuality, but it's hard to put a number on things like that.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Good point ;-) AFAIK, ASCII is a subset of UTF-8.